# Joomla - display number of articles published each month

Tags: joomla, article

How do I create a module that would display the number of articles in one category that have been published each month. Something similar to WordPress, eg.

```
December 2016 (3)
November 2016 (5)
```

etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should follow joomla tutorial to create a new module, that's quite simple : https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module/en

Once you have created the hellow world module as described in tutorial, you should modify the file helper.php and create a new function :

```
public static function getPublicationsByMonth(){

    $db     = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query  = $db->getQuery(true);

    $query->select('DATE_FORMAT(created, "%M %Y") as date, count(*)')
        ->from('#__content')
        ->where('state = 1')
        ->group('date');

    $db->setQuery($query);

    return $db->loadObjectList();

}
```

Then in tpl/default.php you should use result of this method to display results as you want.